# avoid loop on useEffect

Tags: reactjs, loops, use-effect

I have a loop that will generate an Array with multiple datas.
I do this loop in `useEffect` like this :

```
export const GeneratedProgram: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  const askedProgram = getFromLocalStorage("program");

  const [program, setProgram] = useState<any>();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (askedProgram) {
      for (let i = 0; i < askedProgram.length; i++) {
        const muscles = Object.keys(askedProgram[i]);
        const numberOfExercices = Object.values(askedProgram[i]);

        const filerByMuscle: any = exercices.filter((exercice) => {
          return muscles.includes(exercice.id);
        });

        const randomExercices = filerByMuscle
          .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
          .slice(0, numberOfExercices);

        setProgram(randomExercices);
      }
    }
  }, [askedProgram]);
```

The console tells me :

```
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded.
```

I tried many ways to set my state differently but no success.

How can I set this new state and avoid the infinite re-render ?

Comment: Why did you include `program` in the dependency array?

Comment: @SinanYaman I tried a lot of things... just forgot to take it off x)

Comment: That is the reason you are getting infinite loops, `setProgram` updates `program`, and since it is in the dependency array, `useEffect` runs again, calling `setProgram`  and so on

Comment: I took it off and still have the infinite loop :/

Comment: Actually yes, `askedProgram` gets a new reference every time the component renders. Try wrapping it with `useMemo(() => ..., [])`

Comment: @SinanYaman I try to use useMemo instead of useEffect you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons you are getting infinite loops.

#### 1. You have `program` state variable inside the `useEffect` dependency array:

Since the `useEffect` you have updates `program`, having `program` in the dependency array cause the component to call `setProgram` infinitely. If you don't use `program` in your `useEffect`, you should take it off.

#### 2. `askedProgram` gets a new reference every time.

Since in JS, `[] === []` is `false`, every time component re-renders, the variable `askedProgram` changes reference, which causes `useEffect` to run again.

Try:

```
const askedProgram = useMemo(() => getFromLocalStorage("program"), [])
```

Comment: Thank you, you rock ! was on this for hours. Thanks for showing me useMemo :)